# Anyone understand why this CSS3 animation not working when changing class by Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, css, css-animations

I'm developing a game that require the tile should be move and animated.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptgamr/kwn5nmau/2/

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('GameController', function ($scope) {
    var SIZE = 4;

    var Tile = function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    var currentIndex = 0;

    var _coordinatesToPosition = function(pos) {
      return (pos.y * SIZE) + pos.x;
    };

    $scope.grids = [];
    $scope.tiles = [];

    $scope.init = function () {
        for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                $scope.grids.push({
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                });

                 $scope.tiles.push(null);
            }
        }
         $scope.tiles[currentIndex] = {x: 0, y: 0};

    };

    $scope.move = function(dir) {
        console.log('move');
        var vector = {
            'left': {x: -1, y: 0},
            'right': {x: 1, y: 0},
            'up': {x: 0, y: -1},
            'down': {x: 0, y: 1}
        };

        var tile = $scope.tiles[currentIndex],
            nextPos = {x: tile.x + vector[dir].x, y: tile.y + vector[dir].y};

        $scope.tiles[currentIndex] = null;

        var nextIndex = _coordinatesToPosition(nextPos);

        console.log(nextIndex);

        tile.x = nextPos.x;
        tile.y = nextPos.y;

        $scope.tiles[nextIndex] = tile;

        currentIndex = nextIndex;
    }

    $scope.init();

});
```

When i press navigation button, the tile is just move to the next position without any animation.

However, when i change the class directly in the DEV tool, i saw the animation working.

Do you know why?

**UPDATED
===========================================================**

So, i found that the element just got insert/remove. There is no instruction for animation.
Animation is the transition from one state to another state. I only have one state, as a result, no transition is working.

I come up with a solution to use $timeout service of AngularJS. The tile is inserted into the new position, however, the class still keep in the old position. After the $timeout call, it will have a new position class. This time, CSS knows how to do the transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwn5nmau/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the tile from the list

$scope.tiles[currentIndex] = null;

and creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you! I added an $timeout, and it now works. Here is the fork  http://jsfiddle.net/kwn5nmau/6/

Answer (score 1):

All of the tiles already exist -- they're just hidden -- so there's nothing to animate.  You could use `ngAnimate` to animate in the `ngIf`, but this probably wouldn't work very well since the animation can come from different directions.

Instead, you should have *one* tile element and use `ng-class` to bind to changes in its class.  This will change its class dynamically and the animation will occur in a good ol' CSS3 fashion.

```
<div class="tiles-container">
    <div ng-class="tileClass"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles track by $index">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwn5nmau/4/

Comment: That's a great solution. However, i need more than only one tile that moving around. So i can not go for your solution.

I found another solution is to put the timeout to update the position. So, at the beginning, the tile have the original position, after the $timeout call, it will have the new position. Because of that, animation works perfectly. You can see my fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/kwn5nmau/6/